# concatenate rows with same id in mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to concatenate `name` with same `pid`.

Below is query that I'm trying. But it gives me error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@tbl1 WHERE pid = tbl1.pid FOR XM' at line 3

```
SELECT *,STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT', ' + tbl1.name
            FROM @tbl1
            WHERE pid = tbl1.pid
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')

FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT  pid
    FROM @tbl1
) tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.pid = tbl1.pid
```

**UPDATE**

sample data

```
pid      name
1        Editor
1        Reviewer
7        EIC
7        Editor
7        Reviewer
7        Editor
19       EIC
19       Editor
19       Reviewer
```

required data

```
1 Editor,Reviewer
7 EIC,Editor,Reviewer
19 EIC,Editor, Reviewer
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using mysql, looks like [MSSQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)

Comment: you are right it's mssql query. how can I achieve this in mysql ?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Why pid 19 is not included ?

Comment: it is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this in mysql

```
select pid,group_concat(name)
from your_table
group by pid
```

It will return you 3 rows including pid and comma separated list of names

> Also note "The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet"

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/MHGXEC75434)